# generating postgis docset documentation with doxygen

Tags: doxygen, postgis

first of all sorry for dumb question, it's my first time here.

I'm trying to generate docset documentation from PostGis 2 and explore it with Dash, the snippet manager for MacOsX (http://kapeli.com/dash/).

There is an existing doxygen documention online here http://www.postgis.org/documentation/postgis-doxygen/, but I need to generate it on my machine.

I downloaded the last trunk from http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/ , then ran doxygen including only some sub-directories:

-loader
-macros
-postgis
-raster
-regress
-topology

and after I ran make in the doxygen html docs directory, tha t nicely produced a Postgis.docset file.

It goes all nicely, but the documentation is a mess, and missed all the comments already present in the docs of Postgis (/doc/ sub-folder).

Do someone have experience in that? Should I exclude/include other sub-folder or point somehow to the existing PostGis documentation in doxygen?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Thanks to Mike!
I wasn't able to run `./configure` and I had to re-download PostGIS code (2.0.1).
The `make doxygen` ran fine changing the `doxygen.cfg` and `doxygen.cfg.in` file as suggested by Dash coder:

```
GENERATE_DOCSET   = YES
SEARCHENGINE      = NO
DISABLE_INDEX     = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW = NO
```

Anyway, the documentation looks awful, I was trying to produce something like the PostgreSQL docset.
In the next step I want to generate the docset manually, linking the html file directly in the sqlite db present in the .docset .  I have problem generating the html documentation in PostGIS

```
make chunked-html
make -C html/image_src images
make -C ../../../liblwgeom liblwgeom.la
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `liblwgeom.la'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [../../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.a] Error 2
make: *** [images] Error 2
```

any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike for the prompt answer, but I wans't satisfied from doxygne output.
Sorry I cannot vote your answer, because I don't have enough reputation.
I ended up downloading the existing documentation from http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ and created per-hand the sqlite db, packed everything in the docset, as explained here http://kapeli.com/docsets/. 
I'll post more detail, if someone in interested.

Comment: @kippixo, did you ever finish and post this docset somewhere?

Comment: Hi, yes there are other docseat ready in [my github repository](https://github.com/kidpixo), as kapeli didn't want to incorporate them in the Dash distribution. I didn't made a new docset for PostGis 2.1, if there is some request I can think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `make` to build this for you. Also, make sure you have [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed on the PATH.

From the source root:

```
./configure
cd doc
make doxygen
```

To build the other components of the documentation, see [doc/README](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/browser/trunk/doc/README).